# GitHub Atom: How to apply a particular syntax highlighting to some files based on name

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cocoapods, atom-editor

How can I configure *GitHub's Atom* to make it automatically set a particular *syntax highlighting* to filenames based on name and/or extensions?

Specifically I want it to automatically set *Ruby syntax highlightning* to Cocoapods' `Podfile`s.

Comment: @rsanchezsaez I've updated my answer to reflect a newer feature of the core Atom package that is much more convenient.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of Atom 1.0.8 this is now possible without the `file-types` package, using a core feature. To achieve this, open the `config.cson` file, and add a section like the following:

`"*":
  # Other config
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.ruby": [
        "Podfile"
      ]`

There is guidance on finding the language scope name here: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name

---

<strike>This is now possible with the `file-types` [third-party package](https://github.com/execjosh/atom-file-types). I used the following syntax:</strike>

`"*":
  # Other config
  "file-types":
    "^Podfile$": "source.ruby"`

This should be placed in the `config.cson` file.

Here's an excerpt from the readme:

## file-types package

Specify additional file types for languages.

### Extension Matchers

Drop the dot before the extension to use extension matchers.

For example, you can associate `.ex_em_el` with `text.xml` in your `config.cson`
as follows:

`'file-types':
  'ex_em_el': 'text.xml'`

### RegExp Matchers

You can match with regular expressions, too.  Most JavaScript regular
expressions should work; but, the system looks for a dot (`.`), a caret (`^`) at
the start, or a dollar (`$`) to identify RegExp matchers.

For example, you can associate `/.*_steps\.rb$/` with `source.cucumber.steps` in
your `config.cson` as follows:

`'file-types':
  '_steps\\.rb$': 'source.cucumber.steps'`

*NOTE:* Extension Matchers take priority over RegExp Matchers.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the file-types package basically doesn't work in modern Atom? (file-types seems to do nothing even when properly configured under Atom 0.177.0, for example?)

Comment: @DavePeck it's still working fine for me (Atom 0.177.0). I posted the information above while using 0.176.0 so it was pretty modern at the time :-) Are you sure you're putting the config in the correct place, as I initially stuck my config at the end of the file, but it needs to be in the `"*"` group. Enable the debug setting for the plugin and search for `file-types` in `config.cson` to check you've got the correct location.

Comment: please add a link on how to find the languages scope name: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name

Answer (score 4):

As of this writing, there is no way to do this short of submitting a PR to the [language-ruby package](https://github.com/atom/language-ruby) or creating your own fork of the language-ruby package.

There is a bug tracking this issue here: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1718

Comment: That is quite sad. Thanks for your answer. I think I'll save the reputation bounty just in case somebody implements it in the next 6 days. I hope you don't find this unfair.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone arriving here looking to add support for template files in php e.g. .tpl, the folloing works in atom 1.10.2. I do not have previous versions so I can't say about earlier versions.

Add this in your config (config.cson) after core:. I added it after `audioBeep: false` line.

```
customFileTypes:
   "text.html.php": [
    "tpl"
   ]
```

Documentation made me go around in circles. Several articles wrongly mention `source.php` where as it should be `text.html.php`

Just getting started with atom coming from npp++ basically as I have struggled with snippet support there and hope atom can do a good job.

Comment: You find the language scope names here: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name

Answer (score 2):

To add to Maurice Kelly's answer (my reputation is too low to comment)
This is now documented at:

https://github.com/atom/flight-manual.atom.io/blob/681c7fe6e69f1f64396ecadfde1323a01e7f5b96/book/02-using-atom/sections/06-customizing.asc

Comment: Thanks for that Andy.