# Atom Editor Syntax Highlighting for ini files as Java Properties

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am using Atom 1.33.0 on MacOS X 10.13 High Sierra

To configure atom to recognize files with the extension ".ini" as Java Properties and apply the appropriate syntax highlighter I checked the following links:

- [GitHub Atom: How to apply a particular syntax highlighting to some files based on name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653727/github-atom-how-to-apply-a-particular-syntax-highlighting-to-some-files-based-o)
- https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-make-atom-recognize-a-file-with-extension-x-as-language-y/26539
- https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51321435/6204861
- https://discuss.atom.io/t/using-customfiletypes-to-change-the-language-for-html/40230

and assumed that the following config.cson would work:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "no"
    themes: [
      "atom-light-ui"
      "atom-light-syntax"
    ]
  customFileTypes:
    'source.Java Properties': [
      'ini'
    ]
...
```

unfortunately this does not have the desired effect.

To find the correct name i opened an example Java Properties ".ini" file as "Plain Text". Then I changed the syntax highlighting manually to "Java Properties" by clicking in the bottom right corner. Then I pressed Alt-CMD-P which showed:
[image: Alt-CMD-P]

So "source.java-properties" should be the correct name.
I modified config.cson accordingly to:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "no"
    themes: [
      "atom-light-ui"
      "atom-light-syntax"
    ]
  customFileTypes:
    'source.java-properties': [
      'ini'
    ]
```

And still it does not work.

**What needs to be changed to make it work?**

Answer (score 1):

the coffeescript parser seems to be very picky about details
The following config.cson works:

```
   "*":
      core:
        customFileTypes:
            "source.java-properties": [
              "ini"
            ]
        disabledPackages: [
          "welcome"
        ]
  ...
```